# Does Lenovo computers have windows system restrictions?

Tags: hard-drive, boot, lenovo-laptop

I have a lenovo Ideapad 330s-15ikb. It came with a windows 10 home. I upgrated to Windows 10 pro. After some days, the Windows 10 system crash with a blue screen then, trying to reboot, the pc gave me the message "Default boot Device missing or boot failed". I tried to install a windows 10 pro system, the disk shows up as 0MB. I boot a linux system to the computer using an external hard drive, Gparted does not detect the hard drive neither.

I thought the hard drive failed. I gave the pc to the guarantee handlers, they called me, they say

> the hard drive doesn't have any problem. The problem is that I can't
>   install any OS then the Windows 10 Home that came with the laptop. If
>   I want to install the windows 10 pro, I will have to pay them 20
>   dollars for it.

I searched on Google about that Lenovo restriction, but I can't find any link.

When I try to install a clean Windows 10 pro, the installer detect my 16Gb Intel optane memory disk and shows it as 13GB (Wich is ok). But it detects the main 1T Hard drive I had the OS running on as 0MB.

Comment: Try to disable Secure Boot in the BIOS.

Comment: They're trying to scam you. If you have a legitimate Windows 10 Pro upgrade, you can use it.

Comment: @harrymc I disabled Secure boot and also change to Legacy mode. But it wasn't allow to boot neither allow me to install the new OS. Could they install a malware that bootsup before the os so that I can't run OS neither install another one?

Comment: @gronostaj I can't install any OS because the hard drive shows as 0MB. I can't neither run the pre-installed Windows 10 home because I got the message "Default boot Device missing or boot failed" when booting.

Comment: @user3502626 - You should delete all partitions on the HDD.  You will be able to install Windows 10 Home at that point, and after it is installed, upgrade to Windows 10 Professional.  **I have no idea whom, Guarantee Handlers are, but they are giving you bad advice.**  Your machine absolutely can run Windows 10 Professional, anyone that tells you otherwise is not telling you the truth.  **You should absolutely NOT disable Secure Boot.**  Disabling Secure Boot is not required in a case like this, it is simply, unnecessary advice that will not solve your problem.

Comment: Windows 10 Pro costs more than Windows 10 Home.  Microsoft wants you to pay for the new license, and there might be a way to pay for the difference instead of the whole cost.  I have paid $30 for no-transfer Windows 10 license, and your guarantee handlers may have a deal with MS to do a $20 upgrade, or they may just be charging you $20 for a pirated version.  Your original question has a lot of extra details that I won't address.  Your machine worked with Windows 10 Pro for several days, then something broke.  A clean install might work, or not, but it will wipe all data from the drive.

Comment: @Ramhound I can't delete neither create partitions because On the windows 10 installer the hard drive shows only 1 partition and it is 0MB. I even try the hard drive on GParted but, the had drive does not show on Gparted (I had the hard drive, an external drive(Linux is on it) and a usb drive. Gparted and fdisk shown only 2 sda disks with weren't one of the hard drive). As I mentioned already, I can install Windows 10 pro or home by myself and I had the laptop running on Windows 10 pro before it crashes days after. **But the disk shows as 0MB and I can't facto-reset (That's the real problem)**

Comment: @ChristopherHostage The laptop does not allow clean install because MS Windows won't install on the 0mb disk. And they also told me that **the problem is not the disk but is the fact I upgraded from Windows 10 home to Windows 10 Pro.** I just don't get that. If it is not the disk, why I can't install a new OS, neither format the disk?

Comment: What would be the reason the Windows 10 pro crashed, and when I rebooted the laptop I got "Default boot Device missing or boot failed"?

Comment: I updated my post by commenting **When I try to install a clean Windows 10 pro, the installer detect my 16Gb Intel optane memory disk and shows it as 13GB (Wich is ok). But it detects the main 1T Hard drive I had the OS running on as 0MB.**

Comment: I will repeat what others have said.  Your system is absolutely compatible with Windows 10 Professional.  Your current problems are not connected to the fact you upgraded to Windows 10 Professional.  You might have a hardware issue, the partition size being reported a 0 MB is a problem, you obviously cannot install an operating system on an optane drive.

Comment: Thanks for updating your question.  SuperUser is not designed for back-and-forth conversations like we're having now.  Finding the right Question allows people to define an Answer.  When you are booting to the Windows install DVD or USB from the boot menu, you might be choosing GPT rather than UEFI originally installed on your hard drive, so the hard drive is not visible.  https://superuser.com/questions/749604

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SATA Devices not showing up when in UEFI mode](https://superuser.com/questions/749604/sata-devices-not-showing-up-when-in-uefi-mode)

Comment: @Ramhound that post is not the same as mine. I don't have problem to boot from a DVD or USB. It's not about UEFI nor legacy mode. Note I got this error message when boot directly to the main hard drive "**Default boot Device missing or boot failed**". And I can boot up a Linux OS from an external hard drive.

Comment: @Ramhound So, in conclusion, what you are saying is that the problem is exactly the hard drive? So the guarantee handlers are wrong saying that the problem is not the hard drive but the OS? Note that they explicitly told me if I pay them the money the will install the Windows 10 Pro or home.

Comment: @user3502626 - You already own Windows 10 Professional per the details in your question, why would you pay anyone to install Windows 10 for you, which is something you can do for free.  I honestly don't know the reason your HDD is reporting as 0 MB, which might be worth the money for somebody else to determine the reason, but be sure you pay for that instead of some license that isn't legitimate from "guaranteed handlers" (who sound extremely shady)

Comment: @Ramhound Thank you for your answers. I'm just gonna sue them. Because I have 5 months guarantee left. They cannot ask me money to fix hardware problems (if it was what they were trying to say. But it's not). Thanks to you all.